# Inheritance vs class as a member of another class

Tags: java, c++, oop, design-patterns, inheritance

This is a theoretical question, I haven't figured a straight well explained answer yet, about object oriented design.
Let's say we have a class of a Music Event, and we would like to implement a Rating class with maybe one int member(stars 1-5) and maybe one getter and one setter function.
Maybe I haven't thought some bigger picture yet?

If we want our **Music Event** class to have ratings (just one not an array), why is it better -if it is- to inherit from the **Rating** class, and not to add a Rating class member inside the Music event class?

in coding:

```
//why is this better...
class MusicEvent:public Rating {
  string name;
  string duration;
  //and other stuff here
}


//...than this 
class MusicEvent {
  string name;
  string duration;
  Rating rating;
 //and other stuff here
}
```

Comment: The old adage says "prefer composition over inheritance".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not better. You answered the question yourself - it **has** a rating, it **isn't** a rating. Ergo, composition is better (i.e. a member).

Inheritance signifies an **is-a** relationship. Composition signifies a **has-a** relationship.

Comment: I would alter the term composition to aggregation because composition inferes some sort of existence criteria. A Music event can exist without a rating.

Comment: @fyr "composition" is the usual term here, and indeed in this model the music event _can't_ exist without a rating (although it may of course be `null`)

Comment: @Alnitak it is not. "Composition" refers to "part of" ... "Aggregation" refers to "has a" .. and its clearly defined by UML. Sorry for being so picky.

Answer (score 0):

The rating should be a *member* - it is an *attribute* of the event (i.e. something that belongs to it).

Deriving from `Rating` would only ever make sense if you wanted to treat many sorts (or "classes") of rateable events as a common set without caring what sort of event they were.

Answer (score 0):

Clearly a `MusicEvent` **is not** a `Rating`, a `MusicEvent` **has a** `Rating`, so that gives you your answer.

However, what you might want to do later is to have an *interface* called `Rateable`, or something like that, with `setRating()` and `getRating()` abstract methods. This might be useful if you at some point in future have lots of different classes, some of which carry a rating and some don't.